# Get all storage keys in ionic storage

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to Ionic app development and I have been following tutorials for the same.

I have been trying to use `IonicStorageModule` but even though there are no errors while running the app in chrome browser mobile view mode, local storage keys are not being generated.

In my `app.module.ts`, I have

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
```

Then I have the following import in `imports` array,

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
```

Now, I created a service, named `user-settings.service.ts`,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class UserSettings {
    constructor(private storage:Storage){}

    favoriteTeam(team,tournamentId, tournamentName) {
        let item = { team: team,tournamentId : tournamentId, tournamentName : tournamentName};
        this.storage.set(team.id , JSON.stringify(item));
    }

    unFavoriteTeam(team) {
        this.storage.remove(team.id);
    }

    getAllFavorites() {
        let items = [];
        return this.storage.forEach((v,k,i) => {
            items.push(JSON.parse(v));
        }).then(() => {
            return items;
        });

    }
}
```

Now in my components class, I am trying to retrieve all the favorites, but it is not working as expected:

```
  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.userSettings.getAllFavorites().then((val) => {
      _.forEach(val,(v,k)=> {
        this.favorites.push(v);
      });
    });

    console.log(this.favorites);
  }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

How to retrieve all the key values from ionic storage?

**Is this the correct way to do? Seems like lot of iterations to me.**

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a late reply. I'm posting this because this will be helpful for someone else.

If you have stored favorite items as separate keys; you can use `forEach` to read all the keys and values.

```
getAllFavorites() {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.storage.forEach((value, key, index) => {
        this.list.push(value);
      }).then((d) => {
        resolve(this.list);
      });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

**Note**: in this sample, i'm just returning values after reading process is completed by storage.

So, you can use this method as follows;

```
this.userSettings.getAllFavorites().then((d) => {
      console.log(d);
});
```

As I see in your code, you should return a `promise` not just a list.

Comment: storage.forEach only returns the first item, while there are 3 items under my IndexedDB storage... To many bugs in Ionic, switching to React Native

Answer (score 0):

You can store all favorite teams at once, something like:

```
this.storage.set('favorites', teams)
```

So, at `ionViewDidEnter` you need to load all favorites (as list) from storage:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.storage.get('favorites', ...).then(val => {
     this.favorites = ...
  }
}
```

Then you just add or remove items from the list and save.

Comment: I am already storing all the fav team details in `favoriteTeam` method and removing the appropriate one in `unFavoriteTeam` method. Why can't I loop on them using .forEach ? Why do I need to set again some favorites array in storage?